# insert & remove subview from UIScrollView while dragging

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have put multiple `UIButton` (as cards) as subview in `UIScrollView` according to array count, fetched from database. Apart from that i am able to succeed to develop Infinite scrolling & it is just working fine. So I have on option called "remember". As soon as i tap on remember, card (`UIButton` as subview) must show up less often in scrolling. How can i achieve this i.e array at particular index must show less often in `UIScrollView`.Any logic or idea? Here is my code till infinite scrolling:

```
-(void)createCards
{     
[self addCardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[entryArray objectAtIndex:      
([entryArray count]-1)]] atPosition:0];

for (int i = 1; i < ([entryArray count]+1); i++) {
    NSString *titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[entryArray objectAtIndex:i-1] ];
    UIButton *buttonView1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [buttonView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, 320, 180)];
    [buttonView1 setTitle:titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    buttonView1.tag=i;
    [scrollViewForCard addSubview:buttonView1];
}

[self addCardWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[entryArray objectAtIndex:0]] atPosition:([entryArray count]+1)];

scrollViewForCard.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480*([entryArray count]+1), 180);
[scrollViewForCard scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320,0,320,180) animated:NO];
}

- (void)addCardWithName:(NSString*)titleString atPosition:(int)position
{
 UIButton *buttonView1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[buttonView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(position*320, 0, 320, 180)];
[buttonView1 setTitle:titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[scrollViewForCard addSubview:buttonView1];
}

#pragma mark scroll view-delegate

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 int randomInt2 = arc4random() % [entryArray count];    
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{    
if (sender.contentOffset.x == 0) {
    [sender scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake((320*[entryArray count]),0,320,180) animated:NO];
}
else if (sender.contentOffset.x == ([entryArray count]+1)*320) {
    [sender scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(320,0,320,180) animated:NO];
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by less often?

Comment: @hasan: less often means it must rarely display in scroll view content

Comment: do you still wonna remove subview. or you want to stop adding remembered card frequantly as the others? does that work for you?

Comment: lets say a card x that is remembered twice times card y. you want card x to appear 50% less times than y card. does this approach work for you?

Comment: yes i want to stop adding remembered card frequently & it doen't matter the number of time card get remebered

Comment: we can do that on adding subview. and we also can remove previous ones. but their place will stay empty. this is hard to achieve.

Comment: go for tableview and it will do that for you.

Comment: table view?? oh!! than, i have to edit all code that i have written :(

Comment: I think so. it's way better. because continuing with the same approach will cause memory problems too. and it will be so complex to understand and modify.

Comment: unless, you discard removing subview. and only adding based on remember tap for each button. is that acceptable?

Comment: why is your scrollview is infinite will you have a finite number of cards :)

Comment: no its not card is remembered only from displayed card..yes i have finite cards..

Answer (score 0):

On remember click you can remove all subviews buttons as follow:

```
while ([self.scrollView viewWithTag:[button tag]] != nil)
        [[self.scrollView viewWithTag:[button tag]] removeFromSuperview];
```

Now, to start showing remember cards less often. define a boolean array with the same length of your original array. set YES value for the remembered card and No value for the un-remembered one to its corresponding position on the array.

I will keep editing.

Comment: can i hide & display a card in scroll view? will its index will occupy by following cards? The main problem is in adding & removing. I found the logic when to show OR when to hide. I know that soemthing should be done in delegates.

Comment: no if you removed a subview others will not move to cover it's place.

Comment: you can do that programmatically. but I suggest that you use tableview rather than scrollview. even if this worked it will bring more problems (bugs) later.